# Adobe Acrobat Copy and Paste Font messed up

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, fonts, adobe-acrobat

How does one copy and paste in Acrobat when fonts are embedded in PDF and not machine?

- I am opening an Adobe PDF and I copy the font from the PDF and then paste it 
  to word and the characters are all messed up. The Character Encoding is off most likely cause default font is not in acrobat.
- If I export it from Acrobat Pro and make another PDF the font in the next PDF is all messed up. Same if I export to a word or HTML.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: This has been answered numerous times : search about identity-h or identity-v encodings

Comment: actually that last hint was very helpful. Sent me in the right direction so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your PDF file has a partially embedded font, which means that not all the font information required for copy/paste is present in the file. Extracting text from this file is very likely to be imposible.